# Sed command to extract group of digits

Tags: sed

I have 3 statements like the following:

```
abcdef       (123)
adf4fggggh   (456)
ssff444fgff  (4667)
```

By using sed command I need to extract last digits i.e `123`,`456`,`4667`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by substituting. This RegEx will match the entire line, capture the numbers and place the numbers back down.

**Assuming that your lines are in a file called file.txt:**

`sed 's/.*(\([0-9]\+\))/\1/' file.txt`

- **s** - [Substitute](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1)
- **/** - [Delimiter](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-2)
- **.*** - Match [0-Many](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-8) of [any character](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-4)
- **(** - Match the bracket
- **\(** - Start of a [capture group](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4)
- **[0-9]\+** - Match *(capture)* [1-Many](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-8) of any [digits in the range of 0 to 9](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-6)
- **\)** - Close the [capture group](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4)
- **)** - Match the final bracket
- **/** - [Delimiter](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-2)
- **\1** - Print the first [capture group](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4) in place of the previous RegEx match
- **/** - [Delimiter](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-2)

Answer (score 1):

grep get the digits between last parentheses :

```
grep -Po '\d+(?=\)$)'
```

or

```
awk -F'[)(]' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/.*(\([0-9]\{1,\}\))[[:blank:]]*$/ s//\1/p' file.txt
```

- posix version with a bit of security (on line that does not correspond)
- you can add a `-\{0,1\}` just before the digit class is negative value could occur (same idea with a `.` if a dotted value could also occur)